# Parsing only valid xml in Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have done a bit of searching and can't quite find a similar scenario to what I am trying to do.

I have the following code that first builds a cursor that is filled up with 
1) xml 2) id.

This works fine until bad xml row is hit (in the second select statement) then it breaks the procedure and does not continue. I need to find a way to skip bad xml in the second select statement and continue building the cursor.

Here is the code:

```
DECLARE
COUNTER NUMBER;

CURSOR CXD_ID_UPDATE IS
    WITH
XMLDATA
   AS
(
SELECT XMLTYPE(X.XMLDOC) XMLD, X.CXD_ID
FROM
   C_XML_DOC X RIGHT OUTER JOIN CPS_POT P ON X.CXD_ID = P.CXD_ID 
   WHERE P.CXD_ID IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT XT.SCAN_DOC_ID AS SCAN_DOC_ID
,X.CXD_ID AS CXD_ID
FROM XMLDATA X, CPS_DOCUMENT DOC,
 XMLTABLE('/HXML/BATCH/FOLDER/DOCUMENTS/DOCUMENT'
 PASSING X.XMLD
 COLUMNS SCAN_DOC_ID VARCHAR2(50) PATH '@ScanDocID') XT
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(XT.SCAN_DOC_ID,'^\d+(\.\d+)?$', '')
AND XT.SCAN_DOC_ID = DOC.DOC_ID;
BEGIN
COUNTER := 0;
FOR REC IN CXD_ID_UPDATE
LOOP   
BEGIN
  UPDATE DOCUMENT SET CXD_ID = REC.CXD_ID WHERE DOC_ID = REC.SCAN_DOC_ID ; 
  COUNTER := COUNTER + 1;

  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
     CONTINUE; 
  END;
 END LOOP;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('UPDATED: ' || COUNTER || ' DOCUMENTS' );
END;
```

Comment: is it possible to populate the data for us in your code, so that we can reproduce your issue? replace your `SELECT FROM (my tables)` by `SELECT 'code1', 'value1' FROM DUAL union all SELECT 'code2', 'value2' FROM DUAL...`

Comment: Please define what you mean by _bad xml_. Are you storing XML as text in a database table column (e.g. varchar2 or clob column) ? Can you force only "valid" XML to be inserted into the table ?

Comment: XML is in a clob column, and no we are not in control of some of the xml that comes into the table so we cant force only 'valid' XML. When i say bad xml, i mean it is un able to be parsed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For those that wanted an answer to this here it is.

I first created a new function:

```
create or replace function isWellFormedXML(P_XML_CONTENT CLOB,         
P_ERROR_MESSAGE OUT VARCHAR2)
return number
as
  PARSING_ERROR exception;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( PARSING_ERROR , -31011 );
  V_VALID_XML XMLTYPE;
begin
  V_VALID_XML := XMLTYPE(P_XML_CONTENT);
  V_VALID_XML := NULL;
 return 1;
 exception
 when PARSING_ERROR then
   P_ERROR_MESSAGE := DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK() ||          DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE();
   return 0;
 when others then
   RAISE;
 end;
```

This is the main function which utilities this utility.

```
DECLARE
 V_ERROR_MSG VARCHAR2(4000);
 COUNTER NUMBER(10);
BEGIN
COUNTER := 0;
FOR R IN (  
SELECT X.CXD_ID CXD,
   X.XMLDOC XML FROM XML_DOC X, POT P WHERE P.CXD_ID = X.CXD_ID
 ) LOOP   
 BEGIN
  IF(isWellFormedXML(R.XML,V_ERROR_MSG)) = 1 THEN
      FOR L IN (
        SELECT D.SCAN_DOC_ID DOCID
        FROM DOCUMENT DOC, xmltable
         ('/HXML/BATCH/FOLDER/DOCUMENTS/DOCUMENT'
            PASSING XMLTYPE.CREATEXML(R.XML)
           COLUMNS SCAN_DOC_ID VARCHAR2(50) PATH '@ScanDocID'  
         ) D  
         WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(D.SCAN_DOC_ID,'^\d+(\.\d+)?$', '')
         AND D.SCAN_DOC_ID = DOC.DOC_ID 
      ) LOOP
      BEGIN
       COUNTER := COUNTER + 1; 
       --DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('CXD '|| R.CXD || ' DOCID ' || L.DOCID);  
      END;
      END LOOP; 
  END IF;   
  EXCEPTION
     WHEN no_data_found THEN
      NULL;
  END;
END LOOP;     
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('TOTAL NUMBER OF DOCUMENTS : ' || COUNTER);
END;
```